# Can Ubuntu be installed on Dell XPS15 9530

Tags: boot

I'm new to the world of Linux, so I apologise in advance if I say something that appears silly to you.

Over the years I have been frustrated by Microsoft operating systems, and the latest upgrade to Win 10 has disgusted me so much that, despite my age (75), I decided to try Linux.  I managed to get Ubuntu running on a trial basis from a USB stick, and I was delighted.  I then tried to install a dual-boot arrangement, but this failed, despite following the advice provided on various forums.  Eventually, I came across a post which suggested that it is too difficult/risky to do it.

I then decided to go the whole hog and install Ubuntu 16.04 in place of Win 10. luckily, I checked with Dell Support site (my PC is Dell XPS15 9530) to see what it had to say.  Among the comments it advised to check with Canonical that my PC is on their approved list.  Much to my dismay the Canonical list of suitable Dell PCs ends with XPS13 systems.  This leaves me in a tantalising quandary.  I know that Ubuntu works superbly (the trial version) but am worried that a full install attempt might leave me with an expensive 'brick'.

Any (comprehensible) advice would be much appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work fairly well. See the answer and comments here [Does Ubuntu work on the 2013 Dell XPS 15 (9530)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413699/does-ubuntu-work-on-the-2013-dell-xps-15-9530)

If you have anything you wanna keep on your computer like documents and pictures, you will need to make a backup of it on some external device or cloud service **or it will be permanently deleted**.

You can't brick a computer in any serious way by installing Ubuntu. A install can in some rare cases cause a soft-brick so it won't boot into the OS, but then it's often easily fixable by some simple setting like [nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it), or simply a matter of reinstalling or installing another OS of your choice. Given the popularity of Ubuntu, Ubuntu is likely one of the OS's with least possibility of causing soft-brick by install.

Welcome on board! :)